# [MongoDB]How to find an object from array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to query single object from an array of objects.

The array looks like this.

```
db.getCollection('user').getIndexes();

[
   {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        }
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "name" : 1
        }
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "admin" : 1
        }
    }
]
```

Don't know how to find an element with "_id" property name in "key" object.

```
db.getCollection('user').getIndexes().[some sorting query];

{
     "v" : 1,
     "key" : {
         "_id" : 1
     }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

Comment: You're trying to query on result of `getIndexes()`, I believe which is not possible !! Cause `.getIndexes()` doesn't accept anything after that to query on. So this `.find()` works on `db.collection()` but on `getIndexes().find()`. You can bring this result of query to code & do what every you wish to..

Comment: @whoami Oh, I didn't know that! Thank you for sharing it with me :)

Answer (score 0):

The `getIndexes` helper in the mongo shell accepts a filter as an argument, like:

```
db.getCollection("user").getIndexes({"key._id":{$exists:true}})
```

From a driver, you can run the listIndexes command similarly:

```
database.runCommand({listIndexes:"user", "key._id":{$exists:true}})
```